# How can I create a loop for arithmetic array operation?

Tags: bash, scripts

a=

```
3664938.434
3005450.144
2550000.085
```

I need to divide all lines of "a" vector by 1000 and save output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
while read num; do echo "scale=3; $num / 1000" | bc; done <file.txt
```

`bash` does not support floating point arithmetic so we need to use `bc`.

Change `scale` to fit the digits after decimal points according to your need.

To save it in the same file:

```
while read num; do echo "scale=3; $num / 1000" | bc; done <file.txt | tee file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

An `awk` way:

```
awk '{printf("%f\n",$1/1000)}'  file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

And a Perl way (assuming you have your numbers stored in a file, one per line):

```
perl -lne 'print $_/1000' file
```

If your values are stored in a bash array:

```
perl -lane 'print $_/1000 for @F'<<<"${a[@]}"
```